# django template: include a *relative* file but don't parse it

Tags: python, django, django-templates

How can one include a file in a django template like `{% include %}` would, but without parsing the file's contents ?

I am aware of `{% ssi %}` but that last one would not accept relative paths and throws '[Didn't have permission to include file]' at me.

EDIT: this is NOT a duplicate of [How can I tell Django templates not to parse a block containing code that looks like template tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160660/how-can-i-tell-django-templates-not-to-parse-a-block-containing-code-that-looks) . As I commented here, I need a directive **to include a whole file**, not a directive to ignore a block inside a template.

---

Note: I'm trying to include angularJs templates which are in the project's directory, but the syntax conflicts with Django template

Comment: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1684/

Comment: @Aya it's not, I'm asking for a directive to include a whole file, not just one block of code.
I'm checking out your snippet anyway, I'll tell you if it works for me

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Comment: >>> django.get_version()
'1.5.1'

Comment: If you can modify the files you want to include, you can add `{% verbatim %}` at the top and `{% endverbatim %}` at the bottom as of Django 1.5.

Comment: I could but I'm trying to avoid it, because I may have to serve the angular templates directly as static files. Plus, it seems very inconvenient to me when an include_raw tag would feel more natural.

Comment: by the way the snippet provided doesn't work and throws this error "cannot import name load_template_source". Could it be because of my django version ?

Comment: Sure. In retrospect, the custom tag looks like the best option - it just seems like that's something that ought to be built-in. With regards to the error, see the comments below the snippet on the page I linked to.

Comment: Apologies for the premature close vote - I realized soon after that it wasn't really a duplicate, but annoyingly, [there's no way to retract the vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/can-we-have-the-ability-to-rescind-a-close-vote-before-it-closes).

Comment: no problem, your snippet solved my problem with a bit of tuning, so thanks you. I'd accept it as an answer.

Comment: Managed to get some helpful folks to cast some reopen votes, and have added as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to have to modify the files you're including, it looks as if the only way to do this is with a custom template tag.

Fortunately, it looks as if someone else has already posted one called [`include_raw`](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1684/) on *djangosnippets.org*, although it was written for an older version of Django, so you'll have to make some modifications along the lines of those mentioned in one of the comments below the snippet.

Comment: thanks again :) . Still don't understand why such a thing isn't included in the framework